# Vote to Close dialog needs some cleanup for the new domain

Tags: bug, closing, arqade-migration

[image: VTC]

There's a few minor quibbles here. First off, and most obviously, the migration path is wrong. It should (presumably) have the monochrome version of the site logo, and shouldn't be meta.gaming.

Secondly, all of the links to the FAQ etc., in all of the various close reasons still point to gaming.stackexchange addresses.

Finally, is "Arqade - Stack Exchange" how we want the site officially represented? I notice that this form is also used on the How to Ask sidebar on Meta, and is also styled in this way on AskUbuntu, but Superuser doesn't use it.

[image][image]

Answer (score 1):

Some of these things have been fixed/clarified in the intervening years:

---

The Migration close box now uses the monochrome logo for Meta:

[image: "What site does this question belong on?" Dialog Box]

The 'How to Ask' Widget (now 'Step 1: Draft your question') uses 'Arqade' without post-fixing the 'Stack Exchange' name any longer:

[image: New "Draft Your Question" widget]

While the migration path currently still uses the full `gaming.meta.stackexchange.com` address, I feel like that point should be split out into a broader discussion. The `arqade.com` domain still ultimately resolves to the full Stack URLs, and the migration box [isn't the only place](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/15011/28182) where the full URLs are used either.