# Have the 'Share' link use our Arqade domain name

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, domain-name

Currently, if you click on 'Share', the URL that is generated uses the Stack Exchange URL, i.e.

```
https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/...
https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/...
```

This could/should use our custom, shorter URL like so:

```
https://arqade.com/q/...
https://meta.arqade.com/q/...
```

Not only will this help solidify the site branding, but will result in share links using less characters in comments [as currently lamented](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13529/28182). What do you think?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined)

---

The mod team reached out to the Community Team for clarification around the decline. There are a few reasons at play:

- **Inconsistency** - Unlike SE sites that use the custom domain as their primary address (such as Serverfault or Ask Ubuntu), `arqade.com` is just a redirect. So there are larger questions to be answered as to whether customizing the share links are a good idea or not.
  <sub>**Speculation:** This might, for example, require research into how this will impact Arqade's rankings in search engines etc.</sub>
- **Dubious value-add** - The change is largely cosmetic - it wouldn't fundamentally change the site in a beneficial way, the current functionality still works and is 'correct', so it's more of a 'nice to have'.
- **Low-priority** - SE has many, more pertinent bugs and feature requests to handle, and not enough people to get to everything, thus this was put into a low-priority bucket.

They did mention that it was a cool idea, and are open to revisiting this in the future, just not the near-term.

Answer (score 1):

I can currently only see advantages using the `arqade` URLs. Those being the ones you bring up :)

I do wonder, however, if their might be obscure reasons not to do so - our current redirect address is still `gaming.stackexchange.com`, after all. I have too little knowledge of how *The Innernette* works to fully appreciate redirects and the effect it has on (HTTP) requests, server load (not too much, obviously, but if e.g. it helps save energy, it might be a worthwhile reason not to), and that kind of esoteric intricacies.